# Prevent specific function after event

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, hover

Hey there i created this little fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/5H5Xq/17/

As you can see, its a quite good working example for sliding image´s.

But one thing is missing:

When i hover throw a paragraph, the "autoslide-function" should be disabled, that why i added this code to the hover-event:

```
event.preventDefault();
```

But the autoslide function is still processed, any advices?? need your help , GREETING´s !

Comment: a) you are not passing any event so you are preventing nothing at all b) you dont want to prevent hover event you want to prevent function proceed

Comment: What do you mean "by hover throw a paragraph" you have no paragraphs in there, do you mean the slider controls? What is the behaviour you expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need do clear interval by using `Clearinterval()`, because slide is happening through the `Setinterval`, something like this.

```
 // Untuk delay gambarnya

var i = 0, max = 3;
myFunction = function(event){
    $(".subbox1").each(function() {anim(this)});
    i += 1;
    if(i >= max) { i = 0; }
}
var interval = setInterval(myFunction, 1000);

$(".slider").hover(function() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    var img = $('<img>'); 
img.attr('src', $(this).attr('data-url'));
    $('#newImage').html(img);
    $('.images').hide();
    return false;
    i += 1;
   // $(".subbox1").each(function() {anim(this)});

});

$(".slider").mouseout(
    function (){
        $('.images').show();
       // $('#newImage').hide();
interval =   setInterval(myFunction, 1000);
    }
);
```

**UPDATED DEMO**

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5H5Xq/33/)

Comment: yea thank´s that´s what i tried to get, one question: when i hover throw, the div-container "First", the image in the data-url should be shown, how to get this added without destroying the autoslide?

Comment: where do you want to show this image when user hover on "First", along with "First" Label"?

Comment: it should replace, or what u mean??

Comment: I mean the place where the image you want to show when user does hover?

Comment: should be displayed in .subbox1 .images

Comment: okay so you want display image of 'First' in place of auto slide? when  user doe mouse out, you want to continute the slide, am I right?

Answer (score 1):

preventDefault refers to the default action of the browser. For example, the default action of a link is to go to a different page. Hover events have no default action, which explains why your preventDefault appears to do nothing. I think what you may mean to do is delay/kill the timer. Try this:

```
var i = 0, max = 3;
var interval;
function restart() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(function(event){
        $(".subbox1").each(function() {anim(this)});
        i = (i + 1) % max;
    }, 5000);
}

$(".slider").hover(function() {
    i = (i + 1) % max;
    restart();
    $(".subbox1").each(function() {anim(this)});
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

If the desired behavior is to prevent animation until mouseout, then you need to do this:

```
function anim(selector) {
    $(".images img", selector).first().appendTo($('.images', selector)).fadeOut(1000);  
    $(".images img", selector).first().fadeIn(1000);
}

// Untuk delay gambarnya
var i = 0;
var max = 3;
var interval;
function start() {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(function(event){
        $(".subbox1").each(function() {
            anim(this);
        });
        i = (i + 1) % max;
    }, 5000);
}

function stop() {
    clearInterval(interval);
}

$(".slider").hover(function() {
    i = (i + 1) % max;
    $(".subbox1").each(function() {
        anim(this);
    });
    stop();
}, function() {
    start();
});
```

Also, since your animation function rearranges the DOM, you may want to devise a way to reference the images based on their original ordering. Otherwise, your hovering may not work as intended.

**EDIT:** In case the second example is unclear, the [hover](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) function can take a mouseleave function as its second parameter.

**EDIT 2:** I've fixed the syntax error in my code in case you still wanted to refer to it.